# Set initial height to responsive container HTML/CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

So, I'm doing my first responsive design, being a control freak it makes me highly irritated, but to the point.

I've made a typical layout with a carousel on the top. The whole page re-sizes fine and that's not a problem.

My problem is, since the slider contains quite big images the content below loads first, then when the slider loads it shifts the content down. That is to be expected and normally I would set-up a fixed height to the slider container in order to prevent that shifting.

Now there is the problem - I can't setup fixed height to responsive container and i don't know how to prevent that content shift.

EDIT

I have created a jsFiddle to explain the problem, but since it caches the image, you will have to run the output html locally to see the content shift.

http://jsfiddle.net/4mZyF/7/

What do you guys usually do? Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the relevant script/html you currently have issues with. If possible in addtion create a fiddle on jsFiddle.net. Just adding a link to a site is not usefull to any future user possibly having the same issue as you when link-rot sets in or your site has changed.

Comment: Thanks for the response, its more of a theoretical question than an issue, please read my post

Comment: What are you using to control the size of the slider? CSS or a JS script?

Comment: so you just dont like the shifting... so how about you wait that the picture is loaded first before you load the rest of the text ?

Comment: @Lukigi: If it is a theoretical question than SO may not be the place to ask it. See FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq on what question to ask here. To quote: `You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.` If it is a theoretical question than maybe http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ may be better to ask the question on but I'm not 100% on that.

Comment: dSquared it's CSS, but Im open to any solution

Comment: @FrançoisWahl the problem is the one I face, but I am open to any solutions like for example displaying content after I fetch the images. Its simply not about correcting my code, but solving a problem.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Updated with jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

It's been years, but recently I had to deal with it; Measure your initial's picture dimensions to get the scale: mine was a 1920X480px image, so scale ratio would be 25%. Assign to the container's css, height: 0;  padding-bottom: 25%; and will work (hopefully) :)

Answer (score 0):

If all your images are the same width / height originally, you could use the width of the slider wrapper to predict the height of the image and set the `min-height` of the wrapper to match:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var widthOfWapper = $('.slider-wrapper').width();
    var widthOfImages = 940;
    var heightOfImages = 480;
    var imageScale = widthOfWrapper / widthOfImages;

    $('.slider-wrapper').css({
        'min-height': (heightOfImages * ImageScale) + 'px';
    });
});
```

Not ideal, but it may work in your scenario.

Comment: thank you for you rasnwer, but setting the min-height would prevent the container from scaling down with the browser window. See here for a simplified version of my problem http://jsfiddle.net/4mZyF/7/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem would actually be solved by the following:

1. Set the dimensions on the image tags
2. Have the first image display by default (they're already in your source)

Comment: Thank you for reply, but if I declare dimensions it still won't work. I have created a jsFiddle to explain the problem, but since it caches the image, you will have to run the output html locally to see the content shift.

http://jsfiddle.net/4mZyF/7/

Comment: Except you missed the dimensions on the image tag:  `<img src="http://www.lukasgladki.co.uk/test.png" width="1600" height="686">`

Comment: If I put height to the image it will work, but it will stretch image and then further deform it if I narrow the browser window down. In order to avoid stretching I've put height: auto; to the image style, but that overwrites the image initial height and brings me back to my initial problem. see here http://jsfiddle.net/4mZyF/11/   am I missing something?

Comment: The fiddle appears to have been modified since it was posted and the image retains the correct aspect ratio as the window resizes.  Isn't that the intent?  Might also want to set the image to `display: block` to get rid of some of that undesirable whitespace.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I don't think we understand each other. With or without declaring size on image I still have problem with content being shifted down after the image loads. IF I only set image size in the <img> tag then the image is 686px height pernamently, which solves the shift problem, but introduces bad ratio problem. In order to counter that, I've set height: auto in styles and posted updated jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/4mZyF/11/), but that brings back the content shift.

Comment: The problem appears to be browser specific:  Opera (my default browser) and Chrome appear to have the desired behavior, but Firefox (starts small and expands) and IE9 (starts full height and contracts) misbehave.  If you want to absolutely control this, the cure just might be worse than the disease.

Answer (score 0):

have you found the fix for this content shift? I am having the exact same issue and am having hard time fixing it as well. 
So far, I created a very fast .hide(1) for displayed li's and then created a slower .fadeIn(300). It works alright, but not perfectly. If you are ok with having the articles slide down you can use .slideDown(), which works really well - mainly because the content slides up on its own and the the article can push it back down. Problem is that I don't want the images to slide down.

Answer (score 0):

Can you store the original size of each image, calculate the width of the space the image will go and thus the height of the image then animate the height of the image's container so text below will move smoothly up and down?

Even then having varying height images move the content up and down with a carousel is hardly going to be nice on the user's eyes unless I misunderstand the concept!